# Do we predict in Physics?

Tags: soft-question

Being just a learner,whatever little I know about the laws of nature,I think we analyze the consequences and the cause of any event happening around us as well as we explain them by the existing laws.We modify our existing laws if they couldn't explain any phenomenon.

I want to ask that can we predict that how a new event(which didn't happened before) would occur and what would be its consequences?

It may look silly but I think that in physics we analyze the consequences and cause of an event which has already happened but we can't predict a new event!

A **new event** for me is an event which never happened before.We do not have experience of a new event.For example:-a colour which is different from VIBGYOR and is even not a combination of VIBGYOR.We see it for the first time.So a **new colour** is a new event.

**EDIT**

Please refer my comment in the conversation section for more clarity.

Comment: What happens, when you drop a ball from 2m height? Can you predict the outcome?

Comment: @DomDoe That's what I am saying,we already know the consequences of an event which we have already experienced.Can we predict the outcome of a new event?

Comment: @Unique Depends on Can we construct a suitable theory on those new type events. Even then not all theories have same prediction power. For example QM lets only to predict statistical distribution of events, but not exact event itself. So there is no final answer to your question

Comment: @Unique what is a 'new event' to you?

Comment: yes, lots of new events https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_general_relativity

Comment: *Please refer my comment in the conversation section for more clarity.* I have done this and I am still unclear on this. It would be best to just edit your question to be more clear

Comment: But I can predict how long the ball takes to reach the ground from 2 m, even though I've never timed this particular drop. To all intents and purposes it is a new event. Perhaps you mean that it's in the same $class$ of events as those we've experienced.    As Physics advances the classes of 'similar' events (similar enough to make predictions about any event within the class) become wider and wider.

Comment: @Aaron Stevens Please see the edited version

Comment: @DomDoe I defined it in my question.

Comment: I think "an event that never happened before" is still not very precise. How can we definitively say an event never happened before?

Comment: Seems like you're talking about a new physical phenomenon.  Still not really sure if I understand the question though.

Comment: It seems to me like you're trying to specifically define a "new event" so that the answer to your question is "no". In other words, you've already made up your mind.

Comment: @JMac yes I am talking about a new phenomenon

Comment: @Javier Yeah, it almost seems to be setting up to ask "does physics predict things which it has no reason to predict?".

Comment: @Unique Since color is almost always defined as something like "the perception generated by the neurons connected to the cells in the eye that respond to electromagnetic radiation in the visible spectrum," such a color couldn't exist without you drastically changing the definition of "color." So what does "color" mean in your example?

Comment: @probably_someone by new colour I meant a colour other than VIBGYOR or of combination of them which we haven't sensed before.

Comment: @Unique So like a colour that we are able to perceive that is outside of the expected spectrum of visible light?  One problem with that example is that light perception is more biology than physics IMO.  As far as physics cares, colour is just part of the electromagnetic spectrum that interacts with parts of the eyes in a different way than the rest of the spectrum.

Comment: *'Please refer my comment in the conversation section for more clarity."* Commens are transient. Any important updates or clarifications should be edited into the question body.

Comment: @Unique But that's the thing: By definition, a color is either a) associated with some kind of electromagnetic radiation from the visible spectrum, in which case it's "some combination of VIBGYOR" (depending on what specifically you mean by VIBGYOR), or b) a purely neurological phenomenon that is completely unconnected with any electromagnetic radiation at all, at which point you're leaving what's commonly called "physics" and entering neuroscience. So either your color can't exist or its analysis is the subject of neuroscience.

Comment: @probably_someone There's always a chance that our receptors aren't fully understood, and can detect some stray wavelength not typically associated with the "visible spectrum".  So it could have something to do with electromagnetic radiation while still being mostly a neuroscience question, but that doesn't change much of what you said.

Answer (score 1):

Prediction is a very important part of physics, and in fact, all science. Prediction is another name for hypothesis generation, which is a critical part of the scientific process.  When exploring a new area of science, we generate hypotheses and test them to see if they're correct. As that science becomes mature, our hypotheses becomes better-informed, to the point where it becomes a prediction. The hallmark of a good scientific theory is its ability to predict - it indicates that any experimental data is concordant with the theory.

Incidentally, using physical laws to make predictions was one of my first labs in high school physics class. We rolled a ball down a ramp and across a table, measuring its horizontal speed. Then, using only a meter stick, we had to place a small cup on the floor to catch the ball at its predicted landing spot, derived from the ball's speed and table's height. We were only allowed one chance to catch the ball - an incorrect prediction meant failing the lab.

Comment: Hello Sir,can we predict a new event(which didn't happened before)?

Comment: Neutrinos were predicted before they were detected (or even looked for).

Comment: ...as were positrons.

Comment: Gravitational redshift, intermediate vector bosons, Higgs boson, etc.

Answer (score 0):

From the physical characteristics of platinum, I can predict the mass of a cube of pure platinum that is 10 kilometres on each side. From its mass I can predict what such a cube would weigh on the surface of the Moon. Has there ever been a $10$ km cube of pure platinum on the surface of the Moon ? Would that count as a "new event" ?

Comment: I have defined new event in edited version of the question.

Comment: @Unique So, as far as we know, there has never been a $10$ km cube of platinum on the surface of the Moon. Certainly no human has ever experienced this event. So this would be a "new event". But we can still predict quite a lot about the consequences of this event, if it ever happened.